# Woocommerce - Restock automatic

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using wordpress and woocommerce for my shop.

I need to restock a variation product and a single product every night.

Ex. I have a product where the stock amount is 30. Then if someone buys the product the amount is 29 - of course. But then the next day, the stock should automatically switch to 30 again.

Does anyone know how to do that? Or create a php/code/function or something?

I got this code, but it doesn't work.

```
    // Add function to register event to WordPress init
    add_action( 'init', 'register_daily_stock_event');

// Function which will register the event
function register_daily_stock_event() {

    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'increase_stock_daily' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'increase_stock_daily' );
    }
}   

function increase_stock_daily() {
    $product = new WC_Product(10); // replace 10 with your own product ID
    if($product->get_total_stock() < 30) {
        $product->set_stock(30);
    }
}
```